# Remove a specific GPG secret key

Tags: fedora, gpg

I have these two secret keys, only one of which is ok:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/myname/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------------
pub   2048R/12345678 2016-06-30
uid                  My Name (the working one) <my@mail.com>
sub   2048R/12335678 2016-06-30
 
pub   2048R/123ww678 2016-08-11
uid                  My Name (the not working one) <my@mail.com>
sub   2048R/1234as78 2016-08-11
```

Now, when I try to delete a key with:

```
gpg --delete-secret-keys My Name
```

I am getting the option to delete only the working one. Why's that?

Can I delete using the ID instead of using the name?

My OS is Fedora 24.

Answer (score 13):

The key identifier can be used to delete.  For you, the command would be

`gpg --delete-secret-key 1234as78`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the identifier instead of the name; that's the safest option.

Answer (score 5):

The `gpg --list-keys` shows you your public keys, your private keys are shown using `gpg --list-secret-keys`.

To remove a key, you need to use the correct delete command for the type of key: `gpg --delete-key [keyID]` for a public key and `gpg --delete-secret-key [keyID]` for a private key.